# Run script for each line and do something based on output

Tags: python, linux, bash

I have a Python script that someone else made. Inside my bash script I would like to execute it for each line in a txt file, using each line as an argument. Then based on the output of the python script, add that line to a new txt file.

At the moment I run

```
sudo python tester.py 10.0.1.1 999 user pass
```

Where "10.0.1.1 999 user pass" would be a line in my txt file.

If that succeeds it spits out "SUCCESS!". This is where I would like to copy that line to a new file.

Now, to make it more complicated I would like to change the python script based on the start of the line. This isnt 100% needed but saves me spliiting the txt file before hand.

eg. If the line starts with "10" use script 1. If it starts with "192" use script 2. Both have the same "SUCCESS!" output.

I have tried this

```
cat list.txt | while read line
do
    python tester.py $line
    if $(...) == "S"*
    then
        $line >> good.txt
    fi
    done
```

Something isnt right though.

Hopefully that made enough sense for someone to be able to help me.

Chris

Comment: Use a `while read` loop to read the file line by line into variables. You can test the first variable to decide which python script to run. Then run the script, passing the variables as arguments. Use `$(...)` to capture the output, and an `if` statement to test if it's `SUCCESS!` and then write to the file.

Comment: Nothing there is anything more than basic shell scripting. What part of it is confusing you?

Comment: I am still a beginner. The little I know if from looking at examples. I have tried this "cat list.txt | while read line; do python tester.py "$line"; done" but nothing prints

Comment: Don't put `$line` in quotes. The python script expects 4 separate arguments, that will combine the entire line as one argument.

Comment: Awesome thanks Barmar removeing the quotes did it. I now have it printing. So how do I monitor the output and copy the line if it printed "SUCCESS!"? Should I still update the question to show what I have? Nevermind you did it :)

Comment: I posted an answer several minutes ago.

Answer (score 1):

By quoting `$line` you're combining all the words in the line into a single argument, but the Python script need 4 separate arguments.

You should read the first field of the line into a variable of its own so you can test it to decide which script to run.

Then assign the output of the script to a variable, test that against `SUCESS!`, and write to the output file if it matches.

```
while read -r ip rest
do
    case "$ip" in
        10.*) script=tester.py ;;
        192.*) script=tester2.py ;;
        *) echo "IP $ip doesn't start with 10 or 192";
            exit;;
    esac
    result=$(sudo python $script $ip $rest)
    if [[ $result == SUCCESS* ]]
    then
        echo "$ip $rest"
    fi
done < list.txt > good.txt
```

Comment: Thanks I didnt spot this. When I try it I get "test.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `$'in\r''
'est.sh: line 4: `    case "$ip" in"

Comment: You have Windows CRLF newlines in your script. Use `dos2unix` to fix it.

Comment: Thanks I cant beleieve I missed that. Changed it over in Notepad ++. I am only getting the errors printing in the output. The reply starts with "SUCCESS!" but there is some other crap after it. I figured adding a star would allow for that? Like this `if [[ $result == SUCCESS* ]] `

Comment: I thought so. It might be worth mentioning that the python script isnt printing anything. It was printing with my first attempt (after you told me to loose the quotes) but not with what you gave me.

Comment: All the output of the script is put into the `result` variable. Do you need to see the output on the terminal as well?

Comment: I dont need to see it but I was wondering if thats why it isnt working. Maybe I should update the OP to show exactly what I am doing as I simplified it to try and make my question clearer.

Comment: It looks to me like result is set as the command, not the return of the command.

Comment: Without `echo` it tries to execute the contents of `$line` as a comment.

Comment: I just want to make sure I explained what I want clearly. What I do now I take each line and manually run it through a python script and wait for the response. If it succeedes I then manually copy that line to another txt file. I am trying to automate this.

Comment: I understand that perfectly, and I think that's what my script does.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183983/discussion-between-chris-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0):

Pass the arguments as distinct elements.

```
while read -a line
do python tester.py "${line[@]}"
done < list.txt > log.txt 2>&1
```

That will also read the file without starting a pointless `cat`, and log your output. Edit details as needed.

You could also use a case statement on ${line[0]} to determine which program to run.